# Anylogic error "the constructor is undefined" in a resource pool

Tags: javascript, simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I was trying to do a simulation of distribution center model using the tips from anylogic to our own, cause they work in similar ways but diferent products and warehouses, so the thing is when a truck came to our center we have to unload in a determinated area thats why we use the "Muelle" agent to determine all the parameters involved in this operation, and when we call this new recourse unit in the resource pool for the unload process the error appears

[Code use in a resource pool:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKVFq.png)

I got the same problem y two resource pool's

[Problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uaUq.png)

Im relatively new in this program and dont know how to fix this cause for the java description, i tought the variable was already defined cause i name it and was giving every value for each parameter so i dont understand.
I attach the file so if someone requires and can inquire more to solve this ill appreciate it so much
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uBQyLr_LyjN9J07y_J_44ha4CSskVP8y/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Muelle` is an agent, you cannot create/instantiate them like Java objects (i.e. `new Muelle(...)`.

You must use the agent constructor that AnyLogic provides: For every agent population, you get `add_myPopulation(...)` and `remove_MyPopulation(...)` methods. You must use those.

So create an empty (?) agent population and use that. Then, call `add_MyPopulationOfMuelle(...)`

Check the help for more info on agent creation and populations

Comment: You mean something like this? 
https://imgur.com/a/TbCYokq
Cause in this case "DescargaMuelles" is an agent population of the agent "Muelle" and when i do this it gives me the following error: https://imgur.com/a/yUMwRgI
And in unit type i have to select "Muelle" agent right? thanks

Comment: check how agent constructors work and what the arguments mean. They must be specified in the correct sequence, this is what the error is trying to tell you. Here is the help: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/dynamic-creation-and-destruction.html